# How to select only specific attributes from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to select only specific attributes from a model(id,name).

The SQL-command can be for example:

SELECT id,name,username FROM Users

Do you know how I can handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a `:select` option on find methods. This allows you to do:

```
User.find(:all, :select => 'id, name, username')
```

The returned objects will be `User` instances with those attributes available.

Or if you really want just the values without wrapping them us as `User` instances. You can add a method to `User` to return them.

```
def self.get_ids_and_names
  self.connection.select_all("select id, name, username from users")
end
```

which will return an array of hashes mapping column name to the value for that row. E.g. `[{'id' => 1, 'name' => 'user1', 'username' => 'username1'}, ... ]`

Comment: In Rails 3: `User.select("id,name,username")`

Answer (score 27):

Pretty old question, but the rails 3 way would be:

```
User.pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
User.find(:all).map(&:id)
```

to get a list of the user ids if you are trying to get a list of user's ids or names

Comment: I had been googling for this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: I dont recommend it this way. Very slow

Comment: This is an answer, but its fairly slow. `User.find(:all)` returns a complete collection of ActiveRecord objects for each item. then with ruby it maps over those objects and returns just the IDs. You've still got that collection waiting to be garbage collected. hopefully your IDs aren't being used for other memory intensive actions. `User.pluck` and `User.select` are more efficient

Answer (score 2):

We can use `select` for `symbol` or `string` such as:

```
User.select("id, name, username")
```

or

```
User.select(:id, :name, :username)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass in an array, like so:

```
Model.all.select ['id', 'title']
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoid, that would be:

```
User.only(:name, :username).where(id: params[:id]).first
```

Answer (score 0):

## SQL

`SELECT id,name,username FROM Users`

## RUBY

`User.select(:id, :name, :username)`

with condition, you can write like:
 `User.select(:id, :name, :username).find_by(:age 22)`

Answer (score 0):

actually for you only need write this

```
@user= User.select(:attributeN, :attributeN......., attributeN)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: @user
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for those looking to get a single field

Client.select(:id) #The ids on an Active::Record collection
Client.select(:id).pluck(:id) #the ids on an Array