# Retrieve only 'id' values from a Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I have an "`User :has_many Articles`" Record Association for which I retrieve user's articles in this way:

```
@user.articles
# => [#<Article id: 1, title: "Title 1">, #<Article id: 2, title: "Title 2">, #<Article id: ..., title: "Title ...">]
```

However, for what I need to do, *I would like to retrieve only article's `id` values* from that association. 
BTW: It should be a more performant operation of the above.

How is it possible to do that in an "direct" way? That is, there is a Ruby on Rails method to accomplish that by keeping unchanged the `:has_many` association statement for both involved models? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select only specific attributes from a model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237557/how-to-select-only-specific-attributes-from-a-model)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection_singular

```
@user.article_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

gotcha:

```
@user.article_ids<< new_id
```

does not work, it seems to be a read-only array