# Specifying attributes of a Rails object passed into a JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, object, attributes

I have an object in Rails that has attributes A, B, C, D, and E.  When passing this object back to the client-side through a JSON object, how can I tell the rails controller to only include attributes A and D in the JSON object?

Within my Users controller, my code is as follows:

```
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @user}
    end
```

This code works, however, the JSON object that is returned contains all the attributes of the @user object.  How can I limit the attributes that are included in the JSON object before anything is sent back to the client?

UPDATE:  lucapette provides some good background about what's happening behind the scenes.  Since there are times when I'd probably want all attributes returned, I ended up using the following code:

```
    format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:only => ["id"])}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
render :json => @user
```

will call `to_json` on the @user object. And the `to_json` method will use the `as_json` method to do its work. So you can easily override the `as_json` to pass only what you want to the clients. Like in the following:

```
def as_json options={}
  {
    attr1: attr1,
    attr2: attr2
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, lucapette.  After reading your response, I looked into the to_json and as_json methods.  Then, I modified my code as follows:  format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:only => ["id"])}.  Seems like there must be some superfluous code in there but I couldn't find another way to make it work.

Comment: yep, you can use the options too. It works fine that way too. It really depends on the situation you have to face.

Answer (score 0):

Nice way over here [How to select only specific attributes from a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237557/how-to-select-only-specific-attributes-from-a-model)
using select to just get certain attributes.

Off course only works if you don't need the other attributes in code. 
As a general way to attack this problem, rabl is worth a look https://github.com/nesquena/rabl