# How to customize json output in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a model for languages and i want to get all the languages as json but the json output looks as follows

> [{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":1,"language":"English","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":2,"language":"Swedish","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":3,"language":"German","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":4,"language":"French","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":5,"language":"spanish","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":6,"language":"dutch","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":"2012-12-03T05:01:18Z","id":7,"language":"Tamil","updated_at":"2012-12-03T05:01:18Z"}}]

but i want to make this as

> {"language":[{"created_at":null,"id":1,"language":"English","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":2,"language":"Swedish","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":3,"language":"German","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":4,"language":"French","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":5,"language":"spanish","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":6,"language":"dutch","updated_at":null},{"created_at":null,"id":7,"language":"Tamil","updated_at":null} ] }

**Update**

```
def index
 @languages = Language.all
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @languages}
 end
end
```

**update 2**

```
    class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
        ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
        has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
    end
```

Comment: doesn't active model serialization gem cover this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
format.json { render json: { "language" => @languages.as_json(:root => false) }.to_json }
```

What this does it to convert the `@languages` array into an array of JSON-formatted hash models with no root keys (using `as_json`), then wraps the result in a hash with a root key "language", and convert that hash into a JSON-formatted string with `to_json`. (See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) for details on including or not including a root node using `as_json`.)

For example, with a model `Post`:

```
posts = Post.all
#=> [#<Post id: 1, name: "foo", title: "jkl", content: "some content", created_at: "2012-11-22 01:05:46", updated_at: "2012-11-22 01:05:46">]

# convert to array of hashes with no root keys
posts.as_json(root: false)
#=> [{"content"=>"some content", "created_at"=>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 01:05:46 UTC +00:00, "id"=>1, "name"=>"foo", "title"=>"jkl", "updated_at"=>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 01:05:46 UTC +00:00}]

# add root back to collection:
{ "post" => posts.as_json(root: false) }
#=> {"post"=>[{"content"=>"some content", "created_at"=>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 01:05:46 UTC +00:00, "id"=>1, "name"=>"foo", "title"=>"jkl", "updated_at"=>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 09:41:42 UTC +00:00}]}

# convert to JSON-formatted string
{ "post" => posts.as_json(root: false) }.to_json    
#=> "{\"post\":[{\"content\":\"some content\",\"created_at\":\"2012-11-22T01:05:46Z\",\"id\":1,\"name\":\"foo\",\"title\":\"jkl\",\"updated_at\":\"2012-12-03T09:43:37Z\"}]}"
```

Comment: this does not work. It just adds another root language and it display as {"language":[{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":1,"language":"English","updated_at":null}},{"language":{"created_at":null,"id":2,"language":"Swedish","updated_at":null}}]}

Comment: The `"languages:"` key should not appear if you include the `:root => false` option (that's what it's for, see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)). I added another root `"language"` because that's what you wanted.

Comment: I saw the docs that you mentioned and you were right but do not know why this is not working. But any way thankyou so much for the response. May be it can work for some others so i will mark your answer as accepted. In case you find some other reason please tell me.

Comment: Is it possible that your `Language` model overrides `as_json` somewhere? Do you use any gems that might modify it? That's the only possibility I can think of.

Comment: I have used "ActiveRecord.Base.include_root_in_json = false" in my language.rb file and now the root disappears but this makes the root disappear for all the methods that were used in the language_controller file.

Comment: Yes that's why I chose to include it as an option instead, so that it would only affect this JSON and not any others. I'm puzzled why `root: false` is not working for you. Can you post your `Language` model code, if it's not too long?

Comment: Actually my language model is so simple and you can see in update 2

Comment: I have another question posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680792/how-can-i-add-values-for-a-field-from-another-model-in-rails/13681020#13681020  could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 3):

override the as_json on the Model you want to customize

```
def as_json options={}
    {
      id: id,
      login: login, 
      name: custom.value, #for custom name
     ...
    }
end

==> or

def as_json(options={})
  super(:only => [:id, :login, :name ....])
end
```

from : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055786/specifying-attributes-of-a-rails-object-passed-into-a-json-object?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Other link: [here](https://quickleft.com/blog/keeping-your-json-response-lean-in-rails/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use rabl gem (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to format your data.

Answer (score 1):

Override `as_json` method in your model, to include associations, hide columns and why not? calling custom methods as they were attributes

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:except => [:created_at,:updated_at],
          :include => { 
            :members => {
                :only => [:role, :account], 
                :include => {
                  :account => {
                    :only => [:name, :subdomain]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          :methods => [:jwt_token]
    )
  end
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Test Teacher",
  "email": "teacher@testing.io",
  "jwt_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwiZXhwIjoxNTY2NzQ0OTQzfQ.HDGu7JiJEQEEpGo7inuXtOZBVQOfTaFquy8dr-QH5jY",

  "members": [{
        "role": "instructor",
        "account": {
            "name": "Testing",
            "subdomain": "test"
         }
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of adding custom json output when you render json is by using gem that provide many json templates-

https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api

Comment: Also check it's usage if you miss one here it is - http://fabrik42.github.com/acts_as_api/