# Add nested attribute to associated model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have three models using Active Record associations:

```
Book Model
has_many :checkouts

User Model
has_many :checkouts

Checkout Model
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :user
```

In my view, I need the book, checkout, and user names from the checkouts.

By using `Book.first.checkouts` I get:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation
  [#<Checkout id: 30,
    checkout_date: "2017-04-13",
    return_date: nil,
    book_id: 118,
    user_id: 1,
    created_at: "2017-04-13 17:43:07",
    updated_at: "2017-04-13 17:43:07"
  >,#<Checkout id: 50,
    checkout_date: "2017-04-13",
    return_date: nil,
    book_id: 118,
    user_id: 1,
    created_at: "2017-04-14 00:33:34",
    updated_at: "2017-04-14 00:33:34">
  ]>
```

But, I would like to the user name, not just the id. I've tried `Book.first.checkouts.map { |c| c.user.name }` but that returns only the name, and I need the rest of the checkout information. Ideally, my data (converted to json) looks something like:

```
{
  name: "Book Name",
  checkouts:  [
    checkout_data: "Today",
    user_name: "Mary"
  ]
}
```

**How can I add the user name to my checkout data?**

Comment: Are you displaying the checkouts individually, i.e. an `.each` loop? You should be able to display `checkout.user.name`

Comment: @Okomikeruko yes, individually through an each loop. `checkout.user.name` works, but it only returns the user name. I need both the checkout and the user name. I'm wondering if I can add it to a virtual attribute, or something like that.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to combine the data of 2 objects: `checkouts` and `user`

Comment: Are you saying you want `checkout.username` to do the same thing as `checkout.user.name`?

Comment: If the goal is to optimize your JSON output, this thread had some answers regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678092/how-to-customize-json-output-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this at your controller:

`render json: @books, include: { checkout: { only: :checkout_date,  include: { user: { only: :name } } }}`

Comment: Didn't know about this! It's really nice

Answer (score 0):

You should preload the data to prevent (N+1) query problem,
For Display possible checkouts for particular book:

```
book_id = <given book id>
book = Book.find(book_id)
checkouts = book.checkouts.includes(:user)
return_hash = {name: book.name, checkouts: []}
checkouts.each do |checkout|
    return_hash[:checkouts] << { checkout_data: checkout.checkout_date,
                                 user_name: checkout.user.name
                               }
end
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was trying out, but I wondered if there was a simpler way. What's the N+1 query problem?

Comment: checkout.user will fire 1 query to database for each checkout, if you use includes :user then all the corresponding users will be pre fetched in single IN query

Answer (score 0):

To include other solutions, I found this worked pretty well:

```
checkouts = book.checkouts.unreturned.map do |checkout|
  checkout.attributes.merge({ user_name: checkout.user.name })
end

{ checkouts: checkouts, available: book.available?, book_id: book.id }
```

`attributes.merge` did the trick.

Comment: Dont use. attributes.merge in a loop, it will take hell lot of execution time as your application grows, i faced the same performance issue in my application, use ruby-prof to see the bottleneck in your code